# WordPress Elementor Pro Hide Or Show Section On Button Click

Tags: custom-wordpress-pages, elementor, wordpress-shortcode

Example link what I want: [Click Here](https://jimfahaddigital.com/service/i-will-design-or-develop-a-responsive-wordpress-blog-website/) Scroll the page footer a little bit on top you see the "See More Reviews" button.

Example Picture Screenshot:

[See More Reviews](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D00DV.png)

[See More Reviews Clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApFrE.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript or jQuery to show or hide section, or if you want to load content then you can use ajax on click, in example they used ajax to show more reviews so if u want it dynamic then use ajax else use jquery to hide or show section.

Search for jQuery.toggle it will work in your case